# How to use an environment variable inside a quoted string in linux/bash

Tags: linux, bash, openfoam

In openfoam, I use foamDictionary to set a string `( 800 "patch" )` for entry `timeVsFile` in `./controlDict` file. As shown, this string includes a double quote.

I define an environment variable `a` to represent the value 800

```
a=800
foamDictionary ./controlDict -entry timeVsFile -set '( $a "patch" )'
```

The correct result should be `timeVsFile  (800 "patch");`

But I get `timeVsFile  ($a "patch");`

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are not expanded in single quote.

```
a=800
echo '($a)'
```

Output:

```
($a)
```

To expand the variables within quoting, use double quote.

```
echo '('"$a"')'
```

Output:

```
(800)
```

It's a jumbled mess, but look at it broken down into `'('`, `"$a"` and `')'`.

So,

```
'( $a "patch" )'
```

this could be done as follows.

```
'( '"$a"' "patch" )'
```

Comment: It works!!! Thank you so much~~~!!!! Many appreciate~!